# Need help implementing flood-fill algorithm

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to create a flood fill algorithm and I keep getting a recursion error with this.  The algorithm seems to have infinite recursion and I cannot pinpoint why. I have looked all over the internet and I cannot find a solution as it seems like my program is correct according to most sources.  There seems to be something wrong however. This is the edited version of the code. The error message is still maximum recursions.

Can I get some help?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import *


w= 75
h= w

flood = Image.new("RGB", (w,h), (0,0,0))

x = 0
y = 0
count = 0

colorlist = []
i = 0

while x < w -1:
    y = 0
    while y < h-1:
        r = random()
        if r < .25:
            flood.putpixel((x,y), (0,0,0))
        else:
            flood.putpixel((x,y), (255,255,255))
        y += 1
    x += 1
x = 0
y = 0
while x < w-1:
    y = 0
    while y < h-1:
        r = random()
        if x == 0 or y == 0 or x == w-1 or y ==h-1:
            flood.putpixel((x,y), (0,0,0))
        y += 1
    x += 1


def floodfill(x,y, d,e,f, g,h,i, image, count):
        count+=1
        (a,b,c) = image.getpixel((x,y))
        if (a,b,c) == (255,255,255):
            (j,k,l) = image.getpixel((x-1,y))
            (m,n,o) = image.getpixel((x+1, y))
            (p,q,r) = image.getpixel((x,y-1))
            (s,t,u) = image.getpixel((x,y+1))
        if count > 990:
            return
        if (a,b,c) == (255,255,255):
            image.putpixel((x,y), (g,h,i))
            floodfill(x-1, y, d,e,f, g,h,i, image, count)
            floodfill(x+1, y, d,e,f, g,h,i, image, count)
            floodfill(x, y-1, d,e,f, g,h,i, image, count)
            floodfill(x, y+1, d,e,f, g,h,i, image,count)


floodfill(2,2, 0,0,0,255,0,0,flood, 0)

flood.save("flood.png")
print("done")
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You don't appear to be checking for x,y being out of bounds - that could lead to an infinite recursion as x rapidly goes left.  Or are you hoping for your borders to take care of that?

Comment: Python has a relatively low limit for recursion, around 1000 - this is a Python trap for someone used to functional languages with tail recursion optimizations like scheme.

Comment: Okay, so I added some more borders and now it does not go out of bounds.  It works for smaller sized images, however when you increase the size of the image, it increases the amount of recursions, which in turn causes it to reach the maximum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has a tendency to throw a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error, even if the algorithm doesn't recurse infinitely and would eventually halt on its own. There are two solutions to this: increase the recursion limit, or switch to an iterative algorithm.

You can raise your recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`. Choose a number higher than the worst-case recursion depth of your algorithm. In your case, that would be the number of pixels in your image, `length * height`.

Changing your algorithm into an iterative one is fairly simple, since it doesn't really matter in what order you paint the pixels, as long as you get them all at least once. A `set` is very well suited to holding unique non-ordered data, so let's use that to store the pixels we need to paint.

```
def floodFill(x,y, d,e,f, g,h,i, image):
    toFill = set()
    toFill.add((x,y))
    while not toFill.empty():
        (x,y) = toFill.pop()
        (a,b,c) == image.getpixel((x,y))
        if not (a,b,c) == (255, 255, 255):
            continue
        image.putpixel((x,y), (g,h,i))
        toFill.add((x-1,y))
        toFill.add((x+1,y))
        toFill.add((x,y-1))
        toFill.add((x,y+1))
    image.save("flood.png")
```

If you do use the iterative method, be sure to put bound checking in it. Otherwise, it might run forever! Or at least until your hard drive is filled by one gigantic `toFill` set.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of recursion, why not flood-fill in a [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) manner? Recursion uses an implicit stack anyway so you've nothing to lose.

And yes, as pointed out in the comments, you should be checking for x and y being out of bounds.

Comment: Did you mean BFS? Because from what I understand from the OPs code, the code seems DFS. correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This has not been tested but is based mostly off the code you provided. It should work and provides an alternative method of implementing the `floodfill` algorithm. The function could be more efficient.

```
import PIL
import random
import collections

WHITE = 255, 255, 255
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
RED = 255, 0, 0

def main(width, height):
    flood = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (width, height), BLACK)
    # Create randomly generated walls
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            flood.putpixel((x, y), BLACK if random.random() < 0.15 else WHITE)
    # Create borders
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if x in {0, width - 1} or y in {0, height - 1}:
                flood.putpixel((x, y), BLACK)
    floodfill(50, 25, RED, image)
    # Save image
    image.save('flood.png')

def floodfill(x, y, color, image):
    # if starting color is different from desired color
    #     create a queue of pixels that need to be changed
    #     while there are pixels that need their color changed
    #         change the color of the pixel to what is desired
    #         for each pixel surrounding the curren pixel
    #             if the new pixel has the same color as the starting pixel
    #                 record that its color needs to be changed
    source = image.getpixel((x, y))
    if source != color:
        pixels = collections.deque[(x, y)]
        while pixels:
            x, y = place = pixels.popleft()
            image.putpixel(place, color)
            for x_offset in -1, 1:
                x_offset += x
                for y_offset in -1, 1:
                    y_offset += y
                    new_place = x_offset, y_offset
                    if image.getpixel(new_place) == source:
                        pixels.append(new_place)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(100, 50)
```

Comment: Okay I got it, it was just a matter of using the setrecursionlimit function.  Thanks to everyone!