# random generation of levels using 2D arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to do random generation of levels using 2D arrays. 0 = emptiness, 1 = wall, how generate levels which have a passable route from a starting point to a finish(yellow circle, appears in a random free spot on the map) location?

```
pole = [[0] * 20 for i in range(20)]
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
        pole[i][j] = random.randint(0, 1)
```

At the moment it just randomizes the ones and zeros and it comes out:
[image]

Comment: The requirement "how to make emptiness (0) not completely covered by walls (1)" is not clear. I am guessing you want to generate levels which have a passable route from a starting point to a finish location?

Comment: @vaizki Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny no, I don't need a labyrinth, I want a lot of ways connected to each other

Comment: @Ilya - *I want a lot of ways connected to each other*: That sounds a lot like a maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to generate a random map just like you do now and them *check with an algorithm* if there is an open route between start and finish. If not, just generate a new map and check again.

A "flood fill" algorithm where you start filling from start and see if the fill reaches the finish spot could work. For algorithm help, see:

[Need help implementing flood-fill algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746766/need-help-implementing-flood-fill-algorithm)